# My img does not load on github but work on local

Tags: javascript, html, github

I'm new at coding HTML and javascript and this is my project.
When I clicked random button, the image doesn't show but when I run on my computer it works. I don't really have any idea what is wrong with it.

This my github page : https://tonyeiei.github.io/scfoodcourt/index.html

This my source github : https://github.com/tonyeiei/scfoodcourt

This my code

```html
<button onClick="randomImg()" class="btn">Random</button>
              <img id="imageid" src="">
              <script language="JavaScript">function randomImg(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var imgName = "random_" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById("imageid").src= "images" + "/" + imgName ;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Also for the code snippet to run correctly you need to provide a link that isn't local but a link across the internet to your GitHub data.

Comment: Also to whoever down voted this person's answer why does no one give a statement on why? I don't really see anything wrong with this question, there isn't a lot of context but that shouldn't be worth a down vote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The file name is case sensitive and the snippet provided is to show that this works when given the correct name of a file.

```html
<button onClick="randomImg()" class="btn">Random</button>
              <img id="imageid" src="">
              <script language="JavaScript">function randomImg(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var imgName = "Random_" + randomNumber + ".jpg"; //<-- Capital R in random
    document.getElementById("imageid").src= "https://github.com/tonyeiei/scfoodcourt/raw/master/images/" + imgName ;
 } //<-- To show you that it works if you give it the correct url
</script>
```

Comment: @Tony Your web page looks amazing by the way I really hope that this random image loader works out really well for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are requesting `random_2.jpg` but your file is called `Random_2.jpg`.

Most computers (servers in particular) use case sensitive file systems and thus care about this sort of thing. Your development machine does not.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds.